# Makefile execute command only if other command returns results

Tags: php, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile with this target :

```
cs-rector: ##@coding-style Refactor code following the PHP version standards staged php files
    @echo "${BLUE}Running rector on git staged files ${RESET}"
    @$(call run-php-script, ./vendor/bin/rector process `git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d | grep "\.php"`)
```

And I would like to call this command :

```
@$(call run-php-script, ./vendor/bin/rector process `git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d | grep "\.php"`)
```

Only if this returns something :

```
git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d | grep "\.php"
```

I have tried several syntaxes that didn't work, like these ones :

```
cs-rector: ##@coding-style Refactor code following the PHP version standards staged php files
    @echo "${BLUE}Running rector on git staged files ${RESET}"
    $(eval FILES=$(shell git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d | grep "\.php"));
    ifneq ($(FILES),)
        @$(call run-php-script, ./vendor/bin/rector process `git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d | grep "\.php"`)
    endif

cs-rector: ##@coding-style Refactor code following the PHP version standards staged php files
    @echo "${BLUE}Running rector on git staged files ${RESET}"
    export FILES=$(shell git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d | grep "\.php");
    ifneq ($(FILES),"")
        @$(call run-php-script, ./vendor/bin/rector process `git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d | grep "\.php"`)
    endif

cs-rector: ##@coding-style Refactor code following the PHP version standards staged php files
    @echo "${BLUE}Running rector on git staged files ${RESET}"
    FILES:=$(shell git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d | grep "\.php")
    ifneq ($(FILES),)
        @$(call run-php-script, ./vendor/bin/rector process `git diff --name-only --cached --diff-filter=d | grep "\.php"`)
    endif
```

These 3 examples are giving me errors, I have not seen other ways to do so that were working for my use case.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Makefiles consist of two distinct "languages" in one file.  Any line that is **not** indented with a TAB character is makefile syntax and parsed by make.  Any line that **is** indented with a TAB character is shell syntax and is passed to the shell to be parsed.  You cannot put makefile syntax into your recipes (indented by a TAB) and you cannot put shell syntax outside of recipes (not indented with TAB).

Comment: The only parts of a recipe (indented with TAB) that are considered by make, are variable and function references like `$(FOO)` or `$(shell ...)` etc. which are expanded first by make before passing the resulting expanded string to the shell to be run.

Comment: Mhh I understand a bit better. Do you have a suggestion that I could use to solve my case ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean "only call this command".  Do you mean you only want to expand the variable (only invoke the `call` function) in some cases?  Or do you mean you only want the shell to run the results of the expansion of the `call` function in some cases?  Without seeing what the `run-php-script` expands to it's not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is make it a single shell command, something like:

```
(test -z ’git diff ...’ && call run-php-script ...) || true
```

If the line gets messy then make it a proper (multi-line) shell script. Then you can use variables and ifneq as you please.